# Who knows a survey about the status of the generalized taxicab-numbers?

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, open-problem

Here :

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_taxicab_number

the generalized taxi-cab-numbers are mentioned and it is stated that no positive integer is known to be expressible by a sum of two fifth powers in more than one way.

> Who knows a site where the status of the taxi-cab-numbers is shown ? For example, partial results or how far the search for examples currently is ?

Comment: Did you follow the references in the WIkipedia article and the references on those pages? (In other words how deep was was your search?)